# Hazelcast CP subsystem only member

Tags: hazelcast

I'm playing with Hazelcast CP subsystem, but my application running in two different datacenters. For many reasons, there is no short time possible to expand this to at least one more datacenter with full application and all in-memory data. But I understand, that without a member in the third locality I§m unable to avoid the split-brain scenario. So the main question is: Is there a possibility to have a Hazelcast member, which doesn't store any data but acts solo as the CP subsystem member?

For a small application acting only as some balancer between my two datacenters, I'll find a hosting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of version 3.12, it's not possible. Hazelcast has the lite members which do not store any data, but lite members cannot be CP members.